# Incorrect Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Working in a project with multiple mater page files.

Trying to create a new aspx page and the default.Master is loading instead of `MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Default.Blank.Master"` as specified in the `<%@ Page %>` directive.

Any thoughts on why this would work on other pages but not this new one?

Comment: It may be a scope issue - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevelopertips/archive/2008/12/31/tip-40-did-you-know-how-to-scope-master-pages.aspx

Comment: Thanks but didn't see anything that stood out in my code

Comment: Why are you using MasterPages in mvc? There are layouts for you...

Answer (score 0):

look at the "pages" element in your web.config http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/950xf363(v=VS.80).aspx